# TeamCity: java.security.cert.CertificateException

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, teamcity

I am trying to create a project from a git url in the form of `https://<local_ip>/myproject.git`
However I am getting the following exception:

`List remote refs failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present`

Since this is our local ip we are not using any ssl certificates or ssh encryption ? Any ideas why I am getting this error ? Is it possible to configure teamcity to ignore ssl checking ?

**EDIT:**

I try the url in my browser. After loging in to the server (which is hosted on a local [gitstack](http://gitstack.com) instance) I get the following error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^registration/login/$
^gitstack/
^rest/
```

Comment: Is the hosted protocol truly HTTPS? What happens if you try to open `https://<local_ip>/myproject.git` with your browser?

Comment: @Muel I am prompted for my login credentials but then I get a page not found error when I login. Our git server is hosted using a local  GitStack instance (http://gitstack.com/). I edited the question for the error

Comment: Okay, it seems as though there's a problem with the certificate being used for HTTPS communication with your GitStack instance. I'd try generating a new self-signed certificate and using it with your GitStack instance. Once this is done you'll need to install it as a trusted certificate with the JRE that you're using to run TeamCity. **Alternatively**, just use a different protocol (eg Git - port 9418?) and you won't have this pain. If it's meant to be an internal tool, then encryption probably doesn't matter too much... :)